# postgreSQL exclusive sorting

Tags: sql, postgresql

Likely just need to step away from the problem for a minute, but this is giving me some trouble.

Write a query that returns the count of all user_id records between 10 and 50, exclusive of the user_ids 20 and 30.

I've got this so far and it's close, but I can't remember how to sort exclusively.

```
SELECT COUNT (user_id)
FROM purchases
WHERE user_id BETWEEN 10 AND 50;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way:

```
SELECT COUNT (user_id)
FROM purchases
WHERE user_id BETWEEN 10 AND 50
and user_id not in (20, 30)
```